# How to create content items/container programatically using dexterity?

Tags: python, plone, dexterity

I have read the manual specifically on manipulating objects under dexterity. http://plone.org/products/dexterity/documentation/manual/developer-manual/reference/manipulating-content-objects/

What I want to do is programatically add contents (either item/container) to current container being created. To be more specific, I am creating a container/folder, once this container has been created it will automatically create items/folders under the parent folder (the one that is newly created manually).

I tried to use this similar code createContentInContainer(folder, 'content_type_name', title=u"title_here"), but i get an error on my instance that says "folder" is not defined. I would like to ask if how this snippet be inserted in the content type? Is it inside a defined function/method inside the class constructor, or how the "folder" should be initially declared/defined?

Thanks.

Comment: I have just found another solution, which uses event handler i.e. IObjectAddedEvent. Thus, in my class i added at the end of the schemas:
<pre>
<code>
@grok.subscribe(IContenttype,IObjectAddedEvent)
def createAttachment(context, event):
    id='new_folder'
    portal_url = getToolByName(context, 'portal_url')
    container = context
    container.invokeFactory(type_name="package.name.attachments", id=id
</code>
</pre>

Answer (score 2):

the answer seems pretty simple: your `folder` must be an `existing instance` of a folderish type. For instance:

```
new_id = plonesite.invokeFactory('Folder', 'some_id')
folder = plonesite[new_id]

from plone.dexterity.utils import createContentInContainer
createContentInContainer(folder, 'example.type', title=u"Foo")
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I would like to clarify on the first statement, does this new_id refers to the newly generated id of a parent folder that will be created?

Comment: yes, take a look at `invokeFactory` declaration https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/PloneFolder.py#L225

Comment: By the way, what does plonesite refers to is it the name of my site or a reserved word? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, it's your plone site. BTW  pls consider marking  the answer as  correct if it solves your  problem

Comment: Thanks @simahawk for your reply, I have posted also an alternative solution that I have found for my problem which works fine.